# Once Installed, getting: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-installer, winui-3

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

I've built a very basic packaged winui3 app, it runs perfectly from Visual Studio, both on debug and release.

I then added a Setup Project to the solution in VS, and set up the files as follows:

> Application Folder - Ico file, Publish Items from Project (Release x64)
>
> User's Programs Menu.SubFolder - Shortcut to Publish Items...

The target is set to x64 and all the configuration is set to x64 and build/deploy in the configuration manager where appropriate. I have the prerequisites for .net 6.0.25 x64 selected as well.

However when I then install through the msi and try to run the app I get the following error

> Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

[image]

I'm aware I've missed something obvious but I can't for the life of me see what it is and everything I've been finding when searching is not quite right.

Comment: You must first "publish" the WinUI3 application (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/package-and-deploy/deploy-overview), then possibly build an msi from the output files.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to add this into your csproj file:

```
<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
```

this can fix any dll not found issues. also if you are creating a msi installer (not msix), so you should Publish your app as a UnPackaged app. if you are creating a MSIX setup, you dont need to change your app mode.